# Finding the max date in elastic search query

Tags: elasticsearch

Can you please help me to convert this sql query to elastic search query?

```
SELECT group,MAX(date) as max_date
FROM table
WHERE checks>0
GROUP BY group
```

Comment: Please add your data model (elasticsearch index). Without that it's really tricky to help you ;)

Answer (score 2):

What if you have your *query* as below, assuming that you're doing an `HTTP POST`. You could simply use [max](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-max-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-metrics-max-aggregation) aggregations of ES in order to get the *max* value and use *terms* within *aggs* in order to get the `GROUP BY` function done.

**Request**:

*yourhost:9200/your_index/_search*

**Request Body:**

```
{
   "query": {
       "query_string": {
           "query": "checks > 0"  <-- check whether this works, if not use the range query 
       }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "groupby_group": {
          "terms": {
              "field": "group"
           },
   "aggs": {
      "maximum": {
          "max": {
              "script": "doc['date'].value"
          }
       }
    }
  }
 }
}
```

For `checks > 0`, you could go with the [range](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#query-dsl-range-query) query as well within the **query**, which could look like:

```
"range" : {
        "checks" : {
             "gte" : 0
         }
 }
```

[This](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_executing_aggregations.html#_executing_aggregations) one could help you on executing aggregations. But please do make sure that you've enabled **scripting** from your *elasticsearch.yml* before you try querying:

```
script.inline: on
```

Hope this helps!